# How can i make livestreams in full hd with Play Station 4 share button?

Tags: ps4

I would like to make my live streams in 1080p (with Play Station 4 share button) to Youtube or Twittch, but the max quality what I can reach now is 720p.
I doesn't find any solution in the internet, even after 1 hour searching, please help me out.
My internet connection speed is 100/100Mps.
I setted the quality to best, and I have no idea what can I do more.

Comment: I don't think that PS4 is powerful enough to stream 1080p.

Comment: Why?
I saw  the teck news, ps4 is now the most powerful console in the market!
Now you say, this powerful device can't handle the 1080p?

Comment: It can handle 1080p when you are playing, but I'm not sure it can stream it.

Comment: Why I get vote down?

Comment: lol it can barely handle 1080p when you're playing either, some games are rendered in 900p

Comment: ? I don't know what you mean. Whether or not it's "nice" it's true. I paid more per GPU than the entire console costs, it's not like it's a big secret that consoles aren't that powerful.

Comment: But the xbox can make live stream on fullhd why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

According to the official [Playstation 4 Ultimate FAQ](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/), the maximum streaming quality is 720p:

> PS4 owners will be able to broadcast their live gameplay footage in HD (720p) via Twitch and Ustream starting with [update] 1.70.

Comment: Well, then I don't search it anymore, thanks buddy :)
I hope we get this feature in the future!

Comment: @user3545446 after some googling, people recommend hardware to record 1080p (the devices that record direct video outputs of the console), but I'm not sure if you can stream with those devices. Also, I don't think that PS4 itself is powerful enough to stream in 1080p. Streaming is a big job- you have to get video output, encode that and send that... in live time.

Comment: That devices is not too cheap.
I buyed this console, for streaming, but now I'm a little disappointed.